# Subplot: Title length size and main title

Tags: matlab, size, title, subplot

[image]

Based on the above subplot:

1) I want to be able to have one main title at the top position which represents the title of all the subplots.

2) I would like to increase the length of the title of each subplot such that the length of the title can be extended as the length of the figure in X-direction.

**About the figure:** I am using this title within the loop which runs 3 times:

```
CO2_label={'Normal CO2','CO2 with 0.1% NPs','CO2 with 0.5% NPs','CO2 with 1% NPs';'-b','-r','-g','-k'};

for i=1:3
    .
    .
    .
    title(['Area where saturation due to ',CO2_label(1,4),' > saturation due to ',CO2_label(1,i)],'Fontweight','Bold')

end
```

Comment: For your 2nd question do you want to change the title font to fit the axes length or you want to split it to several lines if the title text does not fit?

Comment: @yuk: As you can see the title of each subplot is divided in 4 lines. I want to extend the width such that all 4 lines can accommodate in one line without changing the font size.

Comment: @S_H  Do you brake the title into 4 lines? I made a simple test with subplots and it does not break the title.

Comment: You have end-of-line characters (\n) in your title string. Where do you get your title from? Can you show this part of your code? You can try to replace: `titlestring = strrep(titlestring,'\n','');`

Comment: Please see the update **about the figure** in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) [SUPLABEL](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7772-suplabel) is the File Exchange submission you can use for the main title. You can also apply x and y labels for a group of subplots.

2) use curly brackets in title call to get strings, not cells:

```
title(['Area where saturation due to ',CO2_label{1,4},...
       ' > saturation due to ',CO2_label{1,i}],'Fontweight','Bold')
```